# Spring Exception Translator on WildFly or JBoss EAP 6.2

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have the following spring xml configuration on my app.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect" />
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
<bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager"/>
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>
<bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />

<context:component-scan base-package="some.package"  />
<jee:jndi-lookup id="brainz-emf" jndi-name="persistence/spring-core-music-brainz" />
<jpa:repositories base-package="some.package.repository" />
```

I having same exception throwing on WildFly or Jboss.

```
23:01:54,332 WARN  [org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext] (MSC service thread 1-3) Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'artistNameRepository': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No persistence exception translators found in bean factory. Cannot perform exception translation.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:529) [spring-beans-3.2.13.RELEASE.jar:3.2.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458) [spring-beans-3.2.13.RELEASE.jar:3.2.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293) [spring-beans-3.2.13.RELEASE.jar:3.2.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223) [spring-beans-3.2.13.RELEASE.jar:3.2.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290) [spring-beans-3.2.13.RELEASE.jar:3.2.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:191) [spring-beans-3.2.13.RELEASE.jar:3.2.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:618) [spring-beans-3.2.13.RELEASE.jar:3.2.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:934) [spring-context-3.2.13.RELEASE.jar:3.2.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479) [spring-context-3.2.13.RELEASE.jar:3.2.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:410) [spring-web-3.2.13.RELEASE.jar:3.2.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306) [spring-web-3.2.13.RELEASE.jar:3.2.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112) [spring-web-3.2.13.RELEASE.jar:3.2.13.RELEASE]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ApplicationListeners.contextInitialized(ApplicationListeners.java:173) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:193) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:87)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.start(UndertowDeploymentService.java:72)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No persistence exception translators found in bean factory. Cannot perform exception translation.
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.detectPersistenceExceptionTranslators(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:142) [spring-tx-3.2.13.RELEASE.jar:3.2.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.setBeanFactory(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:117) [spring-tx-3.2.13.RELEASE.jar:3.2.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationRepositoryProxyPostProcessor.<init>(PersistenceExceptionTranslationRepositoryProxyPostProcessor.java:44) [spring-data-commons-1.7.3.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.TransactionalRepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.setBeanFactory(TransactionalRepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:85) [spring-data-commons-1.7.3.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeAwareMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1534) [spring-beans-3.2.13.RELEASE.jar:3.2.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1502) [spring-beans-3.2.13.RELEASE.jar:3.2.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521) [spring-beans-3.2.13.RELEASE.jar:3.2.13.RELEASE]
    ... 20 more
```

This happens over and over again....

I searched Stack Overflow over and over again and questions answered haven't solved the problem 
(the HibernateAdpater and the HibernateExceptionTranslator) ....

It seems such exception is related with the application running on JBoss container.

Comment: Why do you declare PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor in the first place? Spring Data JPA sets that up for the repositories already. PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor is not required either as `<context:component-scan … />` activates that transparently. Are you sure the shown configuration is actually identical to the one causing the stack trace? `HibernateJpaDialect` is a `PersistenceExceptionTranslator` and thus should be found.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply,

Indeed i figured out some issues in the configuration, created a j2ee lookup on the data source and configuring a DefaultPersistenceUnitManager and a LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean seems that solved the problem with the configuration.

F.Y.I. same config also worked on WebSphere and OpenJpa.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect" />
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
<bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager"/>
<bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />

<jee:jndi-lookup id="mysic-brainz-ds" jndi-name="java:/jboss/datasources/MB"/>

<bean id="pum" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager">
    <property name="persistenceXmlLocations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath*:META-INF/persistence.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="defaultDataSource" ref="mysic-brainz-ds"/>
</bean>

<bean id="music-brainz-emf" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitManager" ref="pum"/>
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="spring-core-music-brainz"/>
</bean>

<jpa:repositories base-package="org.nanotek.repository" />
<context:component-scan base-package="org.nanotek"  />

<jee:local-slsb id="artistService" jndi-name="java:app/core-ejb/ArtistService"
    business-interface="org.nanotek.service.ArtistService" />
```

also moved the config behind an EJB with an annoted interceptor...

Regards.